# Animation stopping after completion and restarting after few seconds

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I wanted to animate a cape of an avatar. The animation works as intended but once the animation completes it wait for 2-3 seconds before restarting. The animation is not as smooth as it should be. I have the attached codepen where I am working on the animation.

Thank you

```
Codepen link :- https://codepen.io/Anonymous3399/pen/mdBqMrr
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but it's possible because you have few changes between the first frames, but a large delay with a linear function. Check [this example in Codepen](https://codepen.io/olegbarabanov/pen/wvryWjw) - it works fine for me

Comment: @OlegBarabanovI checked your example but in that example also there's delay once animation completes and a new one starts. If you increase the animation timing from 1sec to 3sec you will see a bigger delay.

Comment: I tried this example in chromium-based browsers and it works for me without obvious delays (I checked on Android and on a windows 10 laptop). In Firefox, the animation did not work at all.
Since animation is not quite stable on different systems, you might want to consider making a fallback using apng, webp, gif or another format.

Answer (score 0):

The keyframes at 100% and 0% should be same as it would complete a cycle.
@keyframes cape {
0% {
d:path('M469.22,274.48c75.54,171.74-79.46,351.74-62.3,630.22,166.84-161.48,225.84-.48,375.25-50,204.59-118.48,386.59-240.48,387.24-456.48-291.65-8-280.65-183-529.49-125.14Z')
}
30% {
d:path( 'M469.22,274.48C369,490.22,170,658.22,216.92,914.7c105.1-48.48,269.1,94.52,355.25,0C635,807.22,860,978.22,949.41,914.7,967,749.22,788,284.22,639.92,273.08Z')}
42%  {
d:path('M469.22,274.48C369,490.22,116.38,684.22,276.92,914.7c105.1-48.48,241.78,57.52,355.25,0,131.53-73.48,291.21,52.52,377.24-71-147-110.48-278.71-514.48-369.49-570.62Z')}
55% {
d:path('M469.22,274.48C369,490.22,176.38,684.22,336.92,914.7c105.1-48.48,211.78,57.52,325.25,0,131.53-73.48,291.89,47.52,377.24-141C865.06,693.22,767.06,329.22,639.92,273.08Z');
}
70%{ d:path('M469.22,274.48C369,490.22,312.73,604.22,366.92,894.7c105.1-48.48,233.81,110.52,325.25,0,117.56-162.48,261.89-88,347.24-276.48-174.35-80.48-272.35-289-399.49-345.14Z')
}
78%{
d:path('M469.22,274.48c-178.81,97.74-63.81,329.74-62.3,630.22,100.49-5.48,253.49,72.52,375.25-50,120.24-181.48,306.24-110.48,337.24-316.48-303-21-232-266-479.49-265.14Z')
}
89%{
d:path('M469.22,274.48c-28.13,117.74-141.13,379.74-62.3,630.22,100.49-5.48,203.17-90.48,375.25-50,227.92,19.52,273.92-200.48,387.24-396.48-311.32,65-335.32-123-529.49-185.14Z')
}
100%{
d:path('M469.22,274.48c75.54,171.74-79.46,351.74-62.3,630.22,166.84-161.48,225.84-.48,375.25-50,204.59-118.48,386.59-240.48,387.24-456.48-291.65-8-280.65-183-529.49-125.14Z')
}
}

this will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @nishant. Can you let me know why we need to keep the keyframes the same. And I tried your code and the delay is removed but another problem arised. Like for the first time animation works perfectly than on second time it really animates very fast missing some frames I guess. Than 3rd time it works perfectly and on 4th time it moves really fast. Link to the codepen with your code :- https://codepen.io/Anonymous3399/pen/ExwQypb. Observer the cape it's really smooth one time and other time it will be very fast.

Comment: If you want to create an animation cycle the animation should end from where it is  started hence it will create a cycle.